# enter does not work in textarea in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, textarea, word-wrap

When I press enter in a textarea which has whitespace attribute is set to nowrap through css, it is ineffective. No new line is created. Instread a simple whitespace appears.
This is only true in IE8. I Have tried current version of Opera,Chrome and Firefox and I have not encountered such problems.
Do you have some solution for this?

Thanks..

I have this:

```
.gwt-TextArea
{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

where gwt-TextArea sets the textarea.

Also, I have tried

```
.gwt-TextArea
    {
    white-space:pre;
    }
```

It seems to give the same result.

Comment: FML, same problem here..

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://www.fourmilab.ch/fourmilog/archives/2005-04/000510.html) says Internet Explorer ignores line breaks `with white-space: nowrap`.

Their fix is to use `white-space: pre`.  Does that get you your desired behavior?

Answer (score 5):

So, the solution is, unfortunately, this -
For Internet Explorer 7, any `white-space` value other than `pre` will cause this issue.
For Internet Explorer 8, any `white-space` value other than `pre-wrap` will cause this issue.

I have not tried Internet Explorer 9, though.
In case this is happening there as well, just create a blank page with (a doctype and) a `<textarea>`, open it and press F12. In the console ("Scripts" tab), type `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")[0].currentStyle.whiteSpace)` and simply use the value that is displayed within the output as the value of the `white-space` property of the `<textarea>`.

**Update**

I tried Internet Explorer 11. In emulation modes since Internet Explorer 7 mode, it behaves like Chrome in quirks mode (meaning, only `white-space: normal` and `white-space: nowrap` cause this issue).
I guess they (unintentionally?) backported some fix to most of the emulation modes.

Comment: This issue still exists in Internet Explorer 11, even if you set `white-space` value to `normal` explicitly.

Comment: @wangkaibule - Chrome ignores new lines if you set it to `normal` or `nowrap`. I guess this is by design. Internet Explorer 11 fixed the rest, though. I updated my answer with data regarding Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be CSS solution? If not, you could assign attribute wrap="off" for textarea.

Comment: I was having inconsistent behavior between IE9 and Chrome 13. Setting the attribute wrap="off" worked the same in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The available options (found here: [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html)), are:

- normal
- nowrap, IE5.5+
- pre, IE6+
- pre-line IE8
- pre-wrap IE8

It might be worth using `white-space: normal` (I don't have IE with which to experiment, but I imagine that `normal` would be available by default if it's possible to alter the state to *ab*normal).

---

Edited, with respect to the OP's comment/response.

Are you using a doctype? (I recommend using `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`)

Assuming that you are, is there any chance you could post a link to a demo-page? Or perhaps post your (x)html and css, to see if there's some manner of style-override, or typo, preventing the css being applied?

Comment: pre-line is not ok, it does not keep spaces and tabs. I tried pre, it does not work. Normal is the wrapped mode, that did not help either. I looked at quirksmode.org. It claims IE8 is fully compatible with respect to pre and nowrap. It does not seem to me so. At least for textareas.