# jQuery textarea append newline behavior

Tags: jquery, textarea, newline, append, behavior

I'm trying to append a strings which end in newlines to a textarea using jQuery. However, different newline tokens show different behavior in Firefox3.5 and IE8, and I can't seem to find a way to use something that works for both browsers.

- `\n` works in FF but not in IE
- `<br/>` and `\r\n` work in IE but not in
  FF
- No luck using `<pre></pre>` tags either

I've seen info on the IE innerHTML issue but I'm not exactly sure how to best approach this problem in jQuery. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Not sure how you are setting the textarea content, but if you use the jQuery `val` method, `\n` works consistently in Firefox and IE (Including IE8):

```
var txt = $("textarea#idhere");
txt.val( txt.val() + "\nSomething here\n\nAgain");
```

Causes the textarea to display:

> Existing content
>   and linebreaks if any.
>   Something here
>
> Again

You can see a demo here that works in FF and IE8: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/unali/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/unali/2/edit)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Would you know how performant is this compared to append()?

Comment: Also, surprisingly, `textarea.empty()` doesn't work when you use `val()`. (It used to work when I used `append()`). You can go back to http://jsbin.com/unali/3/edit to see it. Really neat tool btw!

Comment: @Suan, it will perform faster than `.append()` because it is setting an attribute vs. messing with the DOM. Also, just call `.val('')` to empty the textarea. In "old school JS" you would get/set a textarea value like this: `var txt = document.getElementById('idhere'); txt.value += "\nSomething here\n\nAgain";` See how it uses an attribute vs. DOM elements?

Answer (score 0):

Does pressing the [enter] key cause a new line in IE8 for you? You may have to do what the answer to this question suggests: [enter does not work in textarea in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282202/enter-does-not-work-in-textarea-in-internet-explorer-8)