# New lines in textarea doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, newline

For IE, I tried several ways to add new lines in textarea without success.

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="myTextarea" rows=4 cols=4 maxlength=250></textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var text= "line1 line2 line3";              
text= text.replace(/\s/g, "\r");
$('textarea[name=myTextarea]').val(text);
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to remove the css associate to the textarea and its work.

```
textarea{
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

The problem is that now I cannot display words in the same line without breaking them. But it requires another question

Comment: In Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Existing question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159622/jquery-textarea-append-newline-behavior

Comment: My problem seems to  be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. I just tried in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/yo6cc45g/

The problem is that you set `cols=4` and line1 contains 5 characters, therefore the number will appear in a new line. Just change the cols attribute to 5 and it will be ok.

```
<textarea name="myTextarea" rows=4 cols=5 maxlength=250></textarea>
```

Comment: in your test that's work but in my application it doesn't work even if I reproduce the same case.

Comment: Did you change `cols=4` to `cols=5`?

Comment: Again, to display words without breaking them, remove `cols=4`