# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I know there are a lot of questions on this issue. But I want to know if there are any alternatives to solve this issue.

PROBLEM:

I want to fetch existing text in database tables and put it in Textarea in HTML. I am using Django framework.

```
$("textarea[name=profileitemdescription]").val("{{item.item_description}}");
```

the above code works when there are no line breaks `\n` in `{{item.item_description}}`.

It puts value in Textarea if the value(`{{item.item_description}}`) is a single line. Otherwise, it is throwing  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.
Any workaround to put value(`{{item.item_description}}`) in Textarea ?

Comment: Replace the newline character in `item.item_description` before using  it

Comment: `item.item_description` may contain paragraph text. I need to display in the same way as I entering into the database. Paragraphs should be there. What should i replace it with?

Comment: store description is one variable and then use that variable to assign value

Comment: @Naroju Use `\n` not `/n` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159622/jquery-textarea-append-newline-behavior

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it is a typo.

Comment: replace new line with `"&#10;"` then use `$("textarea").html(newtext)`

Comment: Any idea how to use replace in Django template language for `item.item_description` ? I it is hard to do it in Jquery as I can't do it as it is throwing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: @guradio, I was able to create a custom filter to replace new line with ` "&#10;" `. This time error is gone but there is no line gap and instead of newline it is just printing "&#10;" in paragraphs.

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: `"&#10;"` is actually joining two lines together.

Comment: Please show your code in view to see how you pass item variable in the view