# How to use jquery to populate textarea but mutliple sentences with line break?

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#user-submitted-title').on('keyup',function(e){
  $('#user-submitted-content').val('Watch this video'+ $(this).val() +'.');
});

});
</script>
```

This will result in:
Watch this video xxx.

I want to add more sentences in new rows...
ass example...

```
val('Watch this video'+ $(this).val() +'.');
val('Watch this best video'+ $(this).val() +'.');
val('Watch this great video'+ $(this).val() +'.');
val('Watch this something'+ $(this).val() +'.');
val('Watch this that'+ $(this).val() +'.');
```

All this in up function, how?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are setting the textarea content, but if you use the jQuery val method, \n works consistently in Firefox and IE (Including IE8):

try this : val('Watch this video'+ $(this).val() +'. \n')

var txt = $("textarea#idhere");
txt.val( txt.val() + "\nSomething here\n\nAgain");
Check below  link and it's answer for more help!

[jQuery textarea append newline behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159622/jquery-textarea-append-newline-behavior])[1](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Mister_A/2m9vzoeh/2/)

[DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Mister_A/2m9vzoeh/2/)