# textarea scrollbar remove automatic wordwrap/ new lines

Tags: asp.net, html

Been searching but not finding a solution.

I've a textarea, asp:textbox, which I try to remove the behavior that text is placed on a second row without the user doing a linebreak. I want it to continue on the same row even thou the textbox itself is not large enough to present all text as long as the user does not press return.

```
runat="server" Width="387" Height="40px" TextMode="MultiLine" onkeypress="MaxTwohundred(this);" Rows="2" style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

white-space:nowrap Does not do the trick.The user can then not do a simple linebreak by pressing the return button.

Thanks.

Edit

Thanks Tim Medora, it works.

Bellow is what I use.

```
 TextMode="MultiLine" 
                style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; " wrap="false"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nDtpL/4/

While it would be nice to use CSS `white-space` to control this behavior, browser support is inconsistent (see comments). Instead, I'm using `wrap="off"` to get the desired behavior (at least in my quick tests on Chrome, IE 9 (and 7 8 emulation mode), and FF).

Here's a similar thread: [enter does not work in textarea in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282202/enter-does-not-work-in-textarea-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: It actually works for me in Chrome, but in FF I don't get the desired behavior. I'll see if I can find a better solution. What browser are you using?

Comment: It does not work in internet explorer for me and that is what most users on the company is using and a demand for me..

Comment: Yeah. IE9 ignores the return key, Chrome works correctly, and FF ignores the style altogether. I'm looking to see if there is a proprietary extension for IE to accomplish this.

Comment: Text keeps expanding until the user hits return on IE 7/8/9 on the PC.  Is the JS fiddle not working for you, or is it not working within your actual page? Perhaps there is another problem.